# Maven Assembly Plugin, Uploading the right zip file

Tags: maven, upload

I have something like the following where I need to generate 2 zip files and finally zip them up to another zip file:

```
        <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>assembly1</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                <finalName>assembly1</finalName>
                                <descriptors>
                                  <descriptor>assembly1.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <attach>true</attach>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>assembly2</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                <finalName>assembly2</finalName>
                                <descriptors>
                                  <descriptor>assembly2.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <attach>true</attach>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>assembly3</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                <finalName>assembly3</finalName>
                                <descriptors>
                                  <descriptor>assembly3.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <attach>true</attach>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
    </plugin>
```

What I am trying to do is creating 2 zip files called assembly1.zip and assembly2.zip, finally zip these 2 zip files into assembly3.zip

Under the target folder, I see the zip files created and in assembly3.zip, I see the assembly1 and 2 zip files as well.

When Maven uploads to the local repo, it randomly picks up one of the zip files and what I want to be uploaded is the assembly3.zip file.

This is what I see in the Maven log:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (assembly1) @ MyTestWar ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: assembly1.xml
[INFO] Building zip: C:\MyTest\target\assembly1.zip

[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (assembly2) @ MyTestWar ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: assembly2.xml
[INFO] Building zip: C:\MyTest\target\assembly2.zip
**[WARNING] Artifact com.test:MyTestWar:zip:1.0.0.11-SNAPSHOT already attached to project, ignoring duplicate**

[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (assembly3) @ MyTestWar ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: assembly3.xml
[INFO] Building zip: C:\MyTest\target\assembly3.zip
**[WARNING] Artifact com.test:MyTestWar:zip:1.0.0.11-SNAPSHOT already attached to project, ignoring duplicate**



**[INFO] Installing C:\MyTest\target\assembly1.zip to C:\Users\myUserName\.m2\repository\
com\test\MyTestWar\1.0.0.11-SNAPSHOT\MyTestWar-1.0.0.11-SNAPSHOT.zip**
```

This is my Maven install plugin where I try to upload Assembly3.zip

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <id>zip-upload</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <packaging>zip</packaging>
                            <artifactId>Assembly3</artifactId>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/assembly3.zip</file>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Though it is mentioned that it got to upload assembly3.zip, for some reason Maven is picking up assembly1.zip.

Also I am interested in those Warnings.

Any help in getting rid of the warnings as well as uploading Assembly3.zip is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<attach>true</attach>
```

only for the assembly you want to upload.  For the other two executions, omit this option.

As for why it is picking a random assembly instead of uploading all three, I'm guessing the assembly ID in your [assembly descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) are all the same.  The error message

> [WARNING] Artifact com.test:MyTestWar:zip:1.0.0.11-SNAPSHOT already attached to project, ignoring duplicate

hints at this.  Even if you have given the zips different *finalName* values, they still inherit the classifier from the ID in the assembly descriptor.